# "composer.lock" does not show the exact version

Tags: php, composer-php, semantic-versioning

According to the [composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#lock-file), `composer.lock` file should always record the exact packages' versions installed in the project.

However, sometimes I can see some packages in `composer.lock` have no exact version number rather they have a range value such as `"^7.0 || ^8.0"`.

What does that mean?

Comment: This lacks a [mcve].

Comment: There is not much to "reproduce", though. This can be seen on any composer project. It's just a misunderstanding about what's actually stored on the lock file.

Comment: Can you share an example of the part that confuses you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are likely not reading the version of the installed packages, which is indeed specified as a discrete version (e.g. `4.1.5`, no range, just a specific version constraint), but the requirements of one of the installed packages.

If you are looking at the contents of `packages`, within `composer.lock`, only  the root packages will have a discrete version number. E.g.:

```json
{
    "_readme": "foo bar",
    "content-hash": "1098098s908019foobar",
    "packages": [
        {
            "name": "somevendor/somepackage",
            "version": "1.2.3" // <-- specific version, no range
            // etc
        }
    ]
}
```

But each for each package the `require` and `require-dev` sections are included (among other things). So if you keep drilling down you'll see stuff like:

```
{
        "name": "somevendor/somepackage",
        "version": "1.2.3" <-- specific version, no range
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/somevendor/somepackage.git",
            "reference": "a035d3d2de85f762233aedbc6522f22ee29e5252"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/somevendor/somepackage/zipball/a035d3d2de85f762233aedbc6522f22ee29e5252",
            "reference": "a035d3d2de85f762233aedbc6522f22ee29e5252",
            "shasum": ""
        },
            "require": {
                "php": "^7.0 || ^8.0" // <-- like here
            }
        }
}
```

etc.

That information is used by composer when installing/updating new packages, so it does not need to traverse all the package's `composer.json` files again each time.

But the specific version number for each **installed** package is correctly declared on `composer.lock`.

Comment: now I can see it 
thanks for your answer 
However, looks like PHP exact version doesn't exist at all in composer.lock, Am I right?

Comment: Nor it should. `composer.lock` records the installed **packages** versions. The PHP runtime is not part of the composer project, but a requirement of the installed packages.